# VBA - Copy and paste columns to a single column & then copy the according heading x times

Tags: excel, vba, loops

My VBA skills are fresh as this is something I've been working on to improve.

I've searched and got some parts of coding, however, I cannot do what I need.
(Each bar represents a cell on excel sheet

- I have a file with headings in Row 1, these headings are dynamic;
  [Example of Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA8ew.jpg)
- As you can see, each heading has a random number of rows below it.
- Goal is to have it like this: [Example of end excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHQVH.jpg)

I understand this is not complicated, but I'm struggling when I need to count, copy and paste the headings according to the numbers of rows each of them has.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `Sheet1` and you want result in `Sheet2` try the following code:

```
Sub RangetoColumn()
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Count As Long
    Dim colHeader As String

    Set CurrentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")    '-->sheet with data
    Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")     '-->sheet to display result
    lastColumn = CurrentSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Count = 1
    For i = 1 To lastColumn
        lastRow = CurrentSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow > 1 Then    '-->check for data below header
            colHeader = CurrentSheet.Cells(1, i).Value
            For j = 1 To lastRow - 1
                TargetSheet.Range("A" & Count).Value = colHeader
                TargetSheet.Range("B" & Count).Value = CurrentSheet.Cells(j + 1, i).Value
                Count = Count + 1
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```